# Insert record in SQL Server from xmlhttp request object

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Can anyone tell me, How to insert one record in SQL Server by using the xmlhttp object and Asp.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will keep my answer as detailed as your question:

You need to create an aspx page that is the target of the XmlHttp object. This page will parse the data from the XmlHttp request and insert the data to the database.